Why is $p_n p_{n+1} + p_n + p_{n+1}$ more likely to be a prime than $p_n p_{n+1}-p_n+p_{n+1}$?
Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. For $n>1$, define

$f(n) = p_n p_{n+1} + p_n + p_{n+1}$
$g(n) = p_n p_{n+1}-p_n+p_{n+1}$

Since $f(n) > g(n)$ and probability that a number $x$ is prime is about $1/\log x$ decreases as $x$ increases, intuitively we expect to find fewer primes of the form $f(n)$ than of the form $g(n)$. However quite counter intuitively, numerical evidences say the opposite. For $n \le 3 \times 10^9$ there is not a single instance where the number of primes of the form $f(n)$ is greater than that of the form $g(n)$ as shown in the graph below. The difference between the number of primes of each type as shown by the green line seems to become smoother hover around $2 \times 10^6$.

Question 1: Why is $p_n p_{n+1} + p_n + p_{n+1}$ more likely to be a prime than $p_n p_{n+1}-p_n+p_{n+1}$?

Just an idea, but it may be related to Chebyshev's bias, because $p_np_{n+1}+p_n+p_{n+1}\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and $p_np_{n+1}-p_n+p_{n+1}\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ for $n\ge 2$.

@KangyeonMoon Interesting thought but my guess is that it is something else  since in Chebyshev bias, the first switch happens at very early $n=2946$ where as here no switch has been observed till $n=3 \times 10^9$ and the gap oscillating within a  range.

That's not how one define a function. Your definitions should not depend of the form of the arguments. You should write instead $f(x,y) = xy+x+y$ and ask about $f(p_n, p_{n+1})$ or even better, since that's what you're really interested here: $f(n) = p_n p_{n+1} + p_n + p_{n+1}$

All primes > 3 are of the form p = 6k +/- 1. I'd check how often each of the four combinations (6k +/- 1, 6k' +/- 1) occurs for consecutive primes. That might explain things.

@gnasher729 If that were an issue one will expect a constant factor in the discrepancy, something like one function is about $\frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ of the other, but that's not what the graph suggest.

Your argument of comparing the size is not very good. The size of $p_n p_{n+1}+p_n +p_{n+1}$ is practically the same of $p_n p_{n+1}-p_n +p_{n+1}$ since the dominant term is $p_n p_{n+1}$. The difference of sizes is negligible for big values of $n$. (And for small values of $n$ you can't really use asymptotic approximations like $\frac{1}{\log x}$ for the probability.)

@jjagmath Even if the size of $p_n p_{n+1} + p_n + p_{n+1}$ is practically the same as that of $p_n p_{n+1} + p_n + p_{n+1}$ the former is still greater so under no obvious reasoning you expect type f be always more frequent than type g. At best you would expect the sign of discrepancy to alternate between positive and negative but for the first 3 billion primes there is not a single negative discrepancy. May be the sign changes happen at Skewes range but $n=3 \times 10^9$ is not extremely small either.

I don't understand this intuition - $E(n) = 2n < O(n) = 2n+1 $ - and so $\dfrac{1}{2n} > \dfrac{1}{2n+1}$. But primes of the form $O(n)$ will obviously dominate.

@dezdichado Not the right example because while $2n$ is always even and is forbidden from being a prime for $n>1$ so the intuition does not apply there is no such obvious restriction on $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ so the intuition applies.

@NilotpalSinha but an "intuition", if it is a good one, should have some generality to it. Yours is singularly based on the fact that $f(n)<g(n).$

@dezdichado Thats is incomplete. It is based on three things 1) the fact that both $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ have no restriction on being primes 2) $f(n) > g(n)$ and 3) data for the first 3 billion primes. Note that 2) is can be applied if and only if 1) holds. Something like this was done in Meijer's improvement of Cramer's conjecture where he did same to improve Cramers model which like your example failed to distinguish between $2n$ and $2n+1$ where has Meijer's improvement treated them differently.

@NilotpalSinha literally your post says:
"Since ()>()
and probability that a number
is prime is about 1/log
decreases as
increases, intuitively we expect to find fewer primes of the form ()
than of the form  ()."
Besides, I don't consider numerical simulation to be a form of mathematical intuition, but rather a computational tool used to either support or disprove an intuition that would typically precede any formal computation.
Either way, it seems like we have very different understandings of what an intuition is.

@dezdichado Recall that the prime number theorem says that the probability that a random number is prime is $1/\log x$ but it does not mean that the probability that that a random even number $x$ is prime is $1/\log x$. So I don't think anybody in number theory will explicitly mention that a function must take at least some prime values first to talk about its primeness. If it take absolutely no prime values like $2n, n > 1$ then talking about its primeness is a waste of time.
